# Conformal map critical point

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read that if $f(z)$ is analytic at a point $z_0$, if $f'(z_0)=0, f''(z_0)=0, .. , f(z_0)^{k-1}=0, f(z_0)^k \ne 0$, then the mapping $w=f(z)$ magnifies the angle at the vertex $z_0$by a factor of $k$.

I cannot seem to find a proof of this - could anybody direct me to one or provide an insight themselves. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introductory complex analysis books are likely to have this fact, perhaps embedded in a larger discussion of the local behavior of analytic functions.

Use the Taylor expansion at $z_0$. It has the form 
$$f(z) = \sum_{j=k}^\infty  (z-z_0)^j   = (z-z_0)^k \left(c_k + \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty  (z-z_0)^{j-k}\right)$$ 
This implies 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^k} = c_k$$
Therefore, a half-line $z=z_0+te^{i\theta}$ is mapped to a curve that is tangent to the line $z=z_0+t c_ke^{ik\theta}$ at $z_0$. This is the magnification of angles by the factor of $k$.